# How to wrap a static class (from .NET) in a 'with' statement

Tags: python, ironpython

I am trying to wrap a .NET library in nice pythonic wrappers for use in IronPython.

A pattern used often in this library is a PersistenceBlock to make database CRUD operations clean and 'all or nothing':

```
try:
  Persistence.BeginNewTransaction()
  # do stuff here
  Persistence.CommitTransaction()
except Exception, e:
  Persistence.AbortTransaction()
  Log.Error(e)
finally:
  Persistence.CloseTransaction()
```

I would like to wrap this in a class that allows this kind of code:

```
with PersistenceBlock:
  # do stuff here
```

this is what I've come up with:

```
class PersistenceBlock():
  def __init__(self):

  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb):
    try:
      Persistence.BeginNewTransaction()
      yield
      Persistence.CommitTransaction()
    except:
      Persistence.AbortTransaction()
      Log.Error(e)
    finally
      Persistence.CloseTransaction()
```

Is this a proper implementation of PEP343? What might I be missing?

The main thing that is throwing me is that Persistence is a static .NET class, and so there is not 'instance' to manage in the normal sense.

I have tried searching, but the word 'with' overwhelms the resutls :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the docs via searching for `context manager` protocol - that's the protocol all objects supposed to work with the `with` statement should implement.

Context managers (i.e. the `__enter__` method) does not need to return anything - only if you want to use the `with ... as ...` syntax. In your `__exit__` method you'll have to do some proper error checks: re-raise the exceptions if there are any and commit if there aren't. Maybe like this:

```
class PersistenceContext():

    def __enter__(self):
        # when opening the block, open a transaction
        Persistence.BeginNewTransaction()

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb):      
        if excinst is None:
            # all went well - commit & close
            Persistence.CommitTransaction()
            Persistence.CloseTransaction()
        else:
            # something went wrong - abort, close and raise the error
            Persistence.AbortTransaction() 
            Persistence.CloseTransaction()
            raise exctype, excinst, exctb
```

For completeness, you could also use the [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator to implement your context using a simple generator:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager     
def PersisenceContext():

    try:
        yield Persistence.BeginNewTransaction()
    except Exception:
        Persistence.AbortTransaction()
        raise
    else:
        Persistence.CommitTransaction()
    finally:
        Persistence.CloseTransaction()
```

Comment: contextlib is probably more idiomatic and simpler to understand than implementing the interface.

Comment: It's certainly easier to write - but I actually doubt it's easier to understand, when writing your first context manager. `enter` and `exit` are at least somewhat self-explaining...

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. FYI, the IronPython version I am stuck with did not support contextlib, but the first example worked exactly as expected. This heads me in the right direction, while I look into version issues with IronPython and contextlib. I also need to do more exception testing to make sure those bases are covered. I'm watching Hettinger's videos to learn more. Thanks!